# Sequence of positives that is expressed as $3n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

[image]

This is a recurrence relation that my solution as a pic maybe the right one but im looking to confirm .

Comment: It seems that you posted the same question twice.

Comment: Yes I dont know how to delete the first one lol can u tell me how ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Looking for confirmation to my solution

Comment: If you are asking for a solution verification then you should put that in the *question,* not in an answer. And please post (MathJax formatted) *text,* not screenshots.

Comment: Sorry Martin R I am like Ramanujan I can do math but not write lol as in I can't write in mathjax  .can y translate? Please

Comment: Again I am sorry i can't write this problem in mathjax and am very indebted to your suggestion that's what it is. ..a recursive a_n

Comment: spend 10 minutes learning matjax, that is simpler than posting pics.